# Append a dictionary into a list in Dynamodb

Tags: python, amazon-dynamodb, boto3

I am using DynamoDB for my Lambda function and to update any item I am using this function ,

```
def update_title(title, val, dynamodb=None):
    if not dynamodb:
        dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    table = dynamodb.Table('variable')

    try:
        response = table.update_item(
        Key={'var_name': title},
        UpdateExpression="set var_value=:p",
        ExpressionAttributeValues={':p': val},
        ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
        )
    except ClientError as e:
        print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
    else:
        return response['Attributes']
```

I want to append a dictionary into a item(list) without requesting the whole item from the server. Is there any way to do ???

Comment: adding a sample current record in dynamo table and input to this lambda and expected record in dynamo table would be helpful. I didn't quite follow the question. you may be looking for [list_append](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Expressions.UpdateExpressions.html) ?

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I saw the list_append but I don't know much about DynamoDB . Can you please help me to change the function . I have a "item" type list in the database and I want to append a new list or dictionary in the item.

Comment: @BaluVyamajala I want to append this python dict 
value = {
   "no": 1,
   "time": "1616570454.7036493"
 }
into the item and after this the item would look like
{
 "var_name": {
  "S": "orders"
 },
 "var_value": {
  "L": [
   {
    "M": {
     "no": {
      "N": "0"
     },
     "time": {
      "S": "1616531166.2660265"
     }
    }
   },
   {
    "M": {
     "no": {
      "N": "1"
     },
     "amount": {
      "S": "3e-05"
     },
     "time": {
      "S": "1616570454.7036493"
     }
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This modified function with list_apend works for me.

```
def update_list_title(title, val, dynamodb=None):
if not dynamodb:
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

table = dynamodb.Table('coindcx_variable')

try:
    response = table.update_item(
    Key={'var_name': title},
    UpdateExpression="set var_value=list_append(var_value, :p)",
    ExpressionAttributeValues={':p': val},
    ReturnValues="UPDATED_NEW"
    )
except ClientError as e:
    print(e.response['Error']['Message'])
else:
    return response['Attributes']
```